# preserve text in state for React function, no Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file, *app.js*, which contains some React code. The code producess something like a rudimentary kanban board. Right now, the user can create a new div for the board, and then edit or drag the div into a column. However, the state is not preserved if the div has been edited before dragging across columns; the div contents will disappear.

I have tried editing the code in the returned div, modifying the isContentEditable property, but to no avail; the state is lost, and the entered content dissapears, leaving an empty div. I am looking into redux, but in a time crunch. I tried  React Context instead of my local state, but that didnt seem to work either.

For reference, here is the code in a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-feather-80261

All help is appreciated, total noob to front end development!

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of code in the question itself instead of an off-site link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unstated` for preserving state as it's simple and effective, check it out at https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated

**EDIT**:
I checked the code and it does not need a store you only needed to use contenteditable package, I've updated the codesandbox check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-blackwell-4l963

Comment: This looks awesome, but if its okay to ask, how could this be integrated into my code? Im having trouble integrating it : /

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-blackwell-4l963